# What is importance of default.txt at .Kre\alias\default.txt

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Visual Studio 2015 Preview Installed. It is working fine but once I get latest version runtime beta2 and beta3. After this If I create MVC6 Project it failed with many assembly reference not found.

When I look at default.txt it changed to beta3. After that when I changed to beta1 it works as expected.

So I have question what is role of that file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default.txt` and all the files under `alias` are aliases for different version of KRE (K Runtime Environment). You can see the installed versions by running `kvm list`.

`default` is special because that is the KRE version used by Visual Studio.

Comment: If so then what is use of version we select from project properties ? Becasue by changing value in Default.txt I can see its effect in VS 2015 preview. Also How can I compile project under different version ? I am doing this I also have query related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999165/assemblyneutral-attribute-in-asp-net-vnext